# Can anyone point me toward a content relevance algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, full-text-search, match, relevance

A new project with some interesting requirements has arrived on my desk.  I need to develop a searchable directory of businesses, with a focus on delivering relevant results based on arbitrary search queries.  The businesses can be of any niche; there's no one area that is more represented than another.

When googling for things like "search algorithm" or "content relevance algorithm," all I get are references to Google's "Mystical Algorithm of the Old Gods" and SEO firms.

Does the relevance value of MySQL's full text `Match()` function have what it takes for the task?  I've never used it, but I'm definitely going to do some testing.  Also, since this will largely be a human edited directory, I can assume that we can add weighted factors like tagging and categories.  What would be a good way to combine these factors with MySQL's `Match()` relevancy?

I'm also open to ideas that I've not discussed here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an example of information retrieval based techniques lookup [TF-IDF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf) or [BM25](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Okapi_BM25).

For machine learning based techniques, lookup [RankNet](http://net.pku.edu.cn/~course/cs410/reading/icml_ranking.pdf) and its variants from MSR.

Answer (score 1):

If you have hand edited data, have a look at [Oracle text search](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/text.111/b28303/toc.htm). In one of my previous projects we had some good results.

I was not directly involved in the database setups, but I know that the results were very welcome. (Before this they had just keyword based search).

Comment: Thanks for this!  I have a requirement to use MySQL, however.

Answer (score 0):

Use a search engine like [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) to index the data.  You can still use MySql to hold the data, but for searches use a search engine.